# Where are the template files of shipping method?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, template

I am looking forward to making custom templates that can replace a few shipping method places:

**1. Shipping method for registered users**

This one I already found and made a custom version

> /app/design/frontend/COMPANY/THEMENAME/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/**available.phtml**

**2. Shipping method for guests**

Not found yet

**3. Shipping method in admin Sales > Orders > Add/Edit Order**

Not found yet

**4. Not sure if there are anywhere else that I need to override.**

Please list if you know any

**Great thanks!**

Answer (score 3):

2. Shipping method for guests  `/app/design/frontend/COMPANY/THEMENAME/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`
3. Not sure if there are anywhere else that I need to override.
   `/app/design/frontend/COMPANY/THEMENAME/template/checkout/cart/shipping.phtml`